# Problem using SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor with @Value annotation in a Stateless Session Bean

Tags: spring, ejb, ejb-3.0

I'm using spring 3.0.5 in JBoss and when I try to use "@Value" annotation like this @Value("${terminal.type}") in an statless Session Bean annotated with @Interceptors(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.clas s), I receive a IllegalArgumentException "'name' must not be null".
No problem with @Autowired annotation.
In SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor class the metadata.inject() method is called with the bean name argument set to null.
Do I need to specify the bean name somewhere ?

(Same problem was asked here by another user: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?94930-Problem-using-SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor-with-Value-annotation, but was unanswered)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be fixed for 3.0.6 and 3.1:

https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8621